# How to move to bottom of the dynamic page using Java + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the number of rows in a page that is completely dynamic. I have the below code to do so. But it is scrolling to a certain extent and fetching only a partial count of the elements. Cannot locate any element at the bottom of the page as it is a dynamic one. How can I resolve this issue?

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(NoOfAssets));
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.moveToElement(elements.get(elements.size() - 1)).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, 1000000000).release().perform();
int noOfAssets = elements.size();
System.out.println(noOfAssets);
```

It is returning 40 rows only. But there are more rows actually. I want to drag the cursor till the bottom of the page as and when the rows get loaded and then get the size.

Comment: Can you share the url incase it is a public url?

Comment: hmm, cannot share .It's a private url.

Comment: Hi! How is going? Did my answer help you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `scroll down` to the end of the page then find the `elements`.However You can use `sendKeys` method to Scroll down pages.Try following code.Let me know how it goes.

---

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        while(true){

            Long height=(Long) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
            System.out.println(height);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.END);        

            if (height==0)
            {
                break;
            }               

        }
```

Comment: System.out.println(height); is always returning 17

Comment: so you mean to say it never comes of the while loop?